# Invalid Hook Call when executing anonymous function using button onClick

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, react-hooks

I am trying to create a submit button in React.

This is the code I have to handle the onClick event:

```js
const handleEditProfileSubmit = () => {
    const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);

    if (newUserEntityDetails.username !== "") {
        newUserEntityDetails.uid = authContext.user.uid;
        axios.put(ENDPOINT + authContext.user.uid, newUserEntityDetails).then((res: any) => console.log(res)).catch((e: any) => console.log(e));
    }
};
```

And this is the code I have for the button:

```js
<Button onClick={handleEditProfileSubmit}>Submit</Button>
```

Which uses the Button material-ui component.

I have tried using `onClick={() => {handleEditProfileSubmit}}`, however this results in the submit button doing nothing.

I have also tried turning the `handleEditProfileSubmit` constant into a function and doing `onClick={handleEditProfileSubmit()}`, however this gets the same error.

I am unsure of what I am doing wrong. The axios API calls work fine in other parts of my code so I think it's not about the API call.

EDIT: This is the code for the entire component.

```
import React, {useContext} from "react";
import Navbar from "../components/navbar";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthContext } from "../Auth";
import { Container } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Paper, Card, CardContent } from "@material-ui/core";
import { MenuList, MenuItem} from "@material-ui/core";
import { Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";

const axios = require('axios');
const ENDPOINT = 'http://localhost:3000/api/user/';

var newUserEntityDetails = {
    uid: "",
    username: ""
}

const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);

const handleEditProfileSubmit = () => {

        if (newUserEntityDetails.username !== "") {
            newUserEntityDetails.uid = authContext.user.uid;
            var a = axios.put(ENDPOINT + authContext.user.uid, newUserEntityDetails).then((res: any) => console.log(res)).catch((e: any) => console.log(e));
            console.log(a);
        }
        
};


const Settings = () => {

    // If there is no user in the session
    if (authContext.user == null) {
        return(<Redirect to={"/login"} />);

    } else {
        return(
            <>
                <Navbar />
                <Container maxWidth="lg">
                <Grid container spacing={3} direction="row" style={{ minHeight: "90vh" }}>
                    <Grid item xs={3}>
                        <Paper>
                            <MenuList>
                                <MenuItem>
                                    <Typography variant="body1">Profile</Typography>
                                </MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem>
                                    <Typography variant="body1">Account Settings</Typography>
                                </MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem>
                                    <Typography variant="body1">Delete Account</Typography>
                                </MenuItem>
                            </MenuList>
                        </Paper>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={6}>
                        <Card>
                            <CardContent>
                            <Typography variant="subtitle2" gutterBottom>
                                Change Username
                            </Typography>
                            <TextField
                                id="outlined-helperText"
                                label="Change Username"
                                helperText="Username must be unique"
                                variant="outlined"
                                onChange = { input => {
                                    newUserEntityDetails.username = input.target.value;
                                }}
                            />
                            <Button onClick={() => {handleEditProfileSubmit}}>Submit</Button>
                            </CardContent>
                        </Card>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
                </Container>
            </>
        );
    }
};

export default Settings;
```

P.S I have been told by my project manager to avoid using classes for components hence I am trying to write functional components

Comment: Two things... First: you cannot instantiate a React Hook inside an inner function. Instead of this, pull the `useContext` to the top level of your component. Second: `onClick={() => {handleEditProfileSubmit}}` this syntax doesn't make sense. You probably meant `onClick={() => handleEditProfileSubmit()}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling Hooks inside function, that's what causing the problem.
As per [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level): `Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function. By following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders`

Declare hook top of your function, you should be fine!!.

```
...all imports

const Settings = () => {
   const authContext = useContext(AuthContext); //This is what you need to do.

   const handleEditProfileSubmit = () => {
        if (newUserEntityDetails.username !== "") {
            newUserEntityDetails.uid = authContext.user.uid;
            var a = axios.put(ENDPOINT + authContext.user.uid, newUserEntityDetails).then((res: any) => console.log(res)).catch((e: any) => console.log(e));
            console.log(a);
        }
        
  };
....
```

Comment: When I put the thing outside the `const`, I get the same issue and none of the pages are rendered at all. I think it has something to do with me not using classes for my components. Is there any way I can put it outside the `const` without having to use classes in React?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle/stackblitz for it. will have a look at it.

Comment: I have just edited the post to include my whole code for the component. Thanks!

Comment: Check my comment. You are not calling `handleEditProfileSubmit` that way

Comment: This answer totally worked for me, I don't know why I didn't think of that! thank you! P.S @VictorOliveira, I have seen your comment and made the necessary changes. Thank you

Comment: @Meowmi you should be using useState to handle the `username` not with global object. I have made some changes on your code and created a [stackbliz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tgg1s8?file=src%2FSettings.js). <-- Check out this link

Comment: @Naren thank you so much for taking the time to edit my code and suggesting improvements. I will definitely consider this and have learnt something today!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);` outside the `handleEditProfileSubmit`.

Comment: When I put it outside the `const`, I get an invalid hook call and none of the pages get rendered

Comment: How did you write the entire component? It would be much better if we could see.

Comment: I have just edited the post to include my code, thanks for the advice

Comment: You need to define `const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);` and `handleEditProfileSubmit ` inside the `Setting`